# Brightness wont change

Tags: brightness, appearance

I tried changing the brightness but it won't dim or brighten using keys or going under applications, it just stays the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check which graphics driver is used to control the brightness

`ls /sys/class/backlight/`

if it responds with a list that includes `intel_backlight` proceed - if not, I can't help you

If you have the intel_backlight then

```
sudo touch /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
gksudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```

Add the lines

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier  "card0"
        Driver      "intel"
        Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
        BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

Logout, and log back in - your backlight should work now.  I got this answer from [itsfoss.com](http://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/)

Comment: sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf

Comment: @user301958 you can use `sudo` rather than `gksudo`, but `gksudo` is recommended for graphical applications.

Answer (score 0):

For me **works**:
*(Lenovo B590, Linux Mint 17)*

Amar Prabhu said: (at www.itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/#comment-1362036392)

> For those who this fix did not work (it didnt for me), do the following:
>
> Update your Grub file, line no 11 in **/etc/default/grub** to
>
> **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"**
>
> update grub using the command
>
> **update-grub**
>
> Reboot and you are done.

HOW TO fix backlight/brightness:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_Graphics#Backlight_is_not_adjustable

HOW TO change GRUB parameters:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_parameters#GRUB

Comment: The above solution can cause in many cases grub to not load Ubuntu at all! I had the same problem with brightness and this solution prevented my laptop from loading the system. Be extra careful with this solution and be sure you know how to undo it while you are inside grub. Check here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/498628/ubuntu-12-04-kernel-3-13-0-30/500812#500812