# ubuntu 12.04 kernel 3.13.0.30

Tags: 12.04, kernel, ati, updates, login

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 with ATI graphics card. Everything was working without any problems until kernel 3.8. During the regular updates Ubuntu suggested to update to kernel 3.13.0.30. After that the operating system is not able to load in normal mode. Grub appears and I can login to failsafe mode with all kernels including 3.13.0.30. I can also login normally when using kernel 3.8. When using 3.13 normal login will endup to a blank screen before lightdm loads (before the login screen).

Comment: Try to update kernel to 3.15 it is  stable release ..... From 3.8 .... And remove 3.13.0.30

Comment: How did you install 3.13 on 12.04 ? You are likely having a problem with the ati video driver and will need to file a bug report against the kernel. The kernel in the 12.04 repositories is 3.2.0.65.77 - http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/linux . Support for custom kernels is minimal at best .

Comment: @bodhi.zazen. it is in the official repositories I think. [http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/kernel/linux-image-3.13.0-30-generic]

Comment: Try updating to [3.13.0-32](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic). If it still does not work then report a bug.

Comment: I think I found the problem. The problem is that in /etc/default/grub there was an option acpi_backlight=vendor which caused the trouble.

Comment: @orestis Did you solve your problem then?

Comment: @Seth. Yes, but I cannot mark the problem as solved as it is put on hold. I found out it appears in Ubuntu 14.04 as well. The thing is that in case brightness adjustment does not work, adding the option "acpi_backlight=vendor" in the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT variable in the /etc/default/grub file is a popular solution which now  causes the booting problem.

Comment: @orestis I've reopened the question. Please post an answer! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out it appears in Ubuntu 14.04 as well. The thing is that in case brightness adjustment does not work, adding the option "acpi_backlight=vendor" in the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT variable in the /etc/default/grub file is a popular solution which now causes the booting problem. Removing the option from the file and updating grub by running "sudo update-grub" solves the problem.